# Usar el mismo codigo sin copiar y pegarlo las veces que necesite (WEB)

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una pregunta, es que tengo un div "maestro" que envuelve muchos otros divs, imgs, etc, el tema es que para subir un nuevo contenido tengo que copiar y pegar este codigo pero cambiando el id de las variables (para cambiar lo que se muestra) y me preguntaba si podía usar el mismo div (copiarlo una vez) y que vaya mostrando automaticamente el contenido.

```
<div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://web.com/<?php echo $imgs[1]; ?>" class="card-img" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"id="test"><?php echo $titlepage[0]; ?></h5>
<!--         <div id="test">
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo $tabla[0]; ?></p>
        </div> -->
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
        <form action="verca.php?url=https://web.com/<?php echo $ahref[20]; ?>" method="post">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Ver receta</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Estoy usando "simple_html_dom.php" para extraer datos de una web. Como se ve ahi, para subir otra "receta" tendria que copiar todo este bloque pero cambiando los `ids` de adentro de los corchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar angular para ello (precisamente lo que necesitas es perfecto para angular), otro modo es usando solo php, como veo que estas usando un archivo con extension.php, perfecto, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($misDatos); $i++): ?>

    <!-- Aqui pondrias los elementos que quieras repetir lo ideal es que fuera de este
    ciclo tengas un formulario y que mandes los datos a esta misma pagina cuando quieras
    agregar nuevos datos -->

    <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
      <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://web.com/<?php echo $imgs[$i]; ?>" class="card-img" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"id="test"><?php echo $titlepage[$i]; ?></h5>
    <!--         <div id="test">
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $tabla[$i]; ?></p>
            </div> -->
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            <form action="verca.php?url=https://web.com/<?php echo $ahref[$i]; ?>" method="post">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Ver receta</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<?php endfor;>
```

la manera en la que puedes enviar los datos a la misma pagina es que en el formulario donde vayas a hacer POST o GET (preferiblemente POST), puedes usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']>"></form>
```

De esta manera se envian los datos del formulario a la misma pagina.

Comment: Bueno... realmente es que  no recuerdo muy bien yo como hacia para enviar los datos a la misma pagina manteniendo los anteriores... pero creo que con el for ahorraras escribir varias vecez lo mismo, sera dinamico deacuerdo a una variable en php.